Using None and Some in pattern matching gives unexpected results
So in the course I'm taking we're trying to write an interpreter in f#. And for this we have to make a small calculator.
For this I was handed out this code:
type Value = INT of int

type Binop = BPLUS | BMINUS | BTIMES

type Rop = RSUM | RPROD | RMAX | RARGMAX

type vname = string

type Exp =
  | CONSTANT   of Value
  | VARIABLE   of vname
  | OPERATE    of Binop * Exp * Exp
  | LET_IN     of vname * Exp * Exp
  | OVER_LIST  of Rop * Exp list //must be non-empty
  | OVER_RANGE of Rop * vname * Exp * Exp * Exp

(* An association list mapping variable names to their values. *)
type SymTab = (vname * Value) list

(* Inserts a variable into the variable table. *)
let bind v k vtab = (v, k) :: vtab : SymTab

(* Look up the value of a variable. *)
let rec lookup v = function
  | (v', k) :: vtab -> if v = v' then k else lookup v vtab
  | _ -> failwith ("unbound variable: " + v)

(* EVALUATION *)

(*****************************************************
 * TODO: Task 2: complete the definition of `eval`. You may also
 * define any auxiliary functions as you see fit, to help express `eval`
 * as cleanly and concisely as possible.
 ****************************************************)

(* The evaluation function. *)
let rec eval (vtab : SymTab) (e : Exp) : Value =
  match e with
    | CONSTANT n -> n
    | VARIABLE v -> failwith "case for VARIABLE not handled"

Where we have to define variable and a couple of other functions ourselves.
I am pretty sure we are not supposed to be changing anything other than what is under TODO.
For Variable my idea was to use pattern matching like they did during the lectures.
So something like this
| VARIABLE v -> 
      match lookup v vtab with
      | Some x -> x
      | None -> failwith "Unknown variable."

So if lookup gives a variable, I just return that and if it doesn't I return an error saying it doesnt exist.
However when I do this I get
"This expression was expected to have type
'Value'
but here has type
''a option' "
Please don't just write the solution but if you can give some hints as to why this is not working I would be very happy.

Looking at the definition of lookup it doesn't seem to return an option but rather a plain value. You have to change its definition and return Some value or None, otherwise it won't type check.

I've amended my answer to take account of your addition, in the hope that it will help you.

If you can't change lookup to return an option, then you can't check for an option in your VARIABLE case. Instead, you should just return the result of calling lookup directly. (Or, since the rules allow you to define your own auxiliary function, you could write your own lookupBetter and match on the result of that, but you'd still have to fail in the None case.)

As I understand your code, vtab is a table of symbols symbolised by a list of tuples (mapping variable with value). Your lookup function searches the symbol table to see if the given variable is found and, if so, returns its value (of type Value). If not, your code throws an exception. Later, in your code, you expect an option<Value> type, as @Gus pointed out.
Instead of throwing an exception in lookup when the variable is not found, you should return None so that it fits with the functional style and with your idea of managing the pattern VARIABLE. I therefore encourage you to modify your code so as not to throw an exception.
For example,
let rec lookup v = function
  | (v', k) :: vtab -> if v = v' then Some k else lookup v vtab
  | _ -> None

If you are entitled to, you should also use a data type that already does what you want (such as Map). If you have to use exceptions, then you should catch them. But I suggest you avoid throwing exceptions in F# when you can get away with it.
If you are not allowed to modify the code above "TODO", then your lookup function won't return an option type, so you'll just have to write :
| VARIABLE v -> 
      let myValue = lookup v vtab // May throw an exception
      myValue

This follows the explanations given above, but adapted to your restrictions (assuming, of course, that you want to return a value of type Value from your | VARIABLE -> ... pattern).

Hi, I should probably have been more clear about this but I am 99% sure we are not supposed to change anything above the comment with "TODO", though I will get clarification of that. If that is the case should I just avoid pattern matching all together?

Your pattern matching on lookup assumes that this function returns an option type, which it doesn't, so yes, you just need to remove the pattern-matching on Some x and None because option<Value> doesn't typecheck with Value.
